# How to find no. Of elements starts with land in selenium drop-down and count them

Tags: java, selenium

```
Select se= new select(locator of drop-down);
List<webelemts> list= se.getoptions();

For(int l: list){}
```

Not sure as I want to select all countries starts ends with land and count the no. Of them and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a `int counter` and initial value will be set to `0`.

also using the below for each loop, you can iterate all the options and using `.getText()` method, you can use `.startsWith` or `.endsWith` like below.

```
int counter = 0;
Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("select web element xpath here")));
List<WebElement> list = se.getOptions();
for (WebElement ele : list) {
    if(ele.getText().startsWith("land") || ele.getText().endsWith("land")) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and then finally print the counter,

```
System.out.println(counter);
```